# Reading from file,appending to lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to:

1. Read from a file
2. Append each string to a list (from the file, separator ',')
3. Iterate through the list and append certain elements to two other lists

---

```
end_server_alias = []
end_server_ip = []
types = []
if sys.argv[1] == '-e':
    with(open(sys.argv[2], "r")) as f:
        types.append(line.rstrip().split(",") for line in f)
        k = 0
        while k < len(types):
            print(types[k])
            if types[2*k] is not None:
                print(1)
                end_server_ip.append(types[2*k])
            if types[2*k+1] is not None:
                print(2)
                end_server_alias.append(types[2*k+1])
            k += 1
    f.close()
```

The .txt file i am reading from is like this:

```
168.1.2.6,www.random1.com 

133.1.3.4,www.random2.com
```

The index is out of bounds is what I get, but I am also not sure if what contained in types is of string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your parser and I'm not too sure about what are you trying to achieve (in terms of testing contents of file). In any case you can read the file into a list by using the following transformation of your code:

```
types,end_server_ip,end_server_alias = [],[],[]
with(open('in.txt', "r")) as f:
    types = [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in f] # Put List syntax to do list compreehension
    k = 0
    while k < len(types):
        print(types[k])
        if types[k][0] is not None: # acess types as index for row, and index for column
            if type(types[k][0]) == type('string'):
                print('Its a String!!!')
            print(1)
            end_server_ip.append(types[k][0])
        if types[k][1] is not None:
            print(2)
            if type(types[k][1]) == type('string'):
                print('Its a String!!!')
            end_server_alias.append(types[k][1])
        k += 1
f.close()
```

, notice I've changed the way you define `types`, the way you access `types elements`, and added a question to see if an `element is a string`.

Notice the list has what would be equivalent to rows and columns so you need to index to rows and columns to access an element. Also asking if an element is None is somewhat strange to me from what I see from your code. Using the instruction to create types will always create strings. If you need numbers you need to convert them yourself. See instructions such as `int` and `float`.

Comment: Thank you , i see that i misunderstood how it works in python.